# How one user can access our server and copy file there

Tags: security, hosting

Can anyone explain how an user can access my hosting account and then upload files there. Is it because I dont change my ftp details frequenltly. Because recently I found in all my domains a sample php file with a name of hacker was uploaded, which I deleted afterwards and change all my related passwords

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like your account has Been compromised. It could be through someone getting hold of your login credentials, but more likely it is down to an insecure script your using on your site. Are you running any apps like Wordpress, phpbb etc? Make sure you are running the latest versions. It sounds like you are renting your hosting space, I would talk to your provider as it may be something they can help with.

Comment: try not accessing your host from unknown networks without SSL or just not at all...

Comment: now the issue has been resolve somehow I managed to get all right back to the old position. I am using joomla CMS for most of my projects and about 40-50 Joomla project are hosted in the same hosting account, I have given some of my client the FTP details to access their space but the problem also arise long before. Its the 4 time I encountered with this. The first time its the iframe attack, but not it seems to have access to someone to my server and uploading files there